# Is it more efficient to use AWS s3 versioning to store gzipped mysql dumps?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip

With my database, we are taking a mysql dump for backup every hour.  We then upload that backup to AWS s3 for safety and redundancy.  We are using versioning to only store the delta of each new backup.  My question is, are we really gaining anything by gzipping the data first?  Is the data going to be scrambled in gzip so that all the data will have to be re-stored with each version?

If we instead store an un-compressed version of the database will we actually save space over time due to more efficient versioning?

I should add that we have been storing the hourly gzipped backup in s3 for several months now using versioning.  But I am unable to figure out in the online interface how to find how much each new version takes up in storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have S3 versioning and EBS snapshots confused. S3 versioning does not store a delta, it stores the entire version each time. Creating a backup where you only pay for the size of the delta is a feature of Elastic Block Store snapshots.

Comment: This is, of course, correct.  But EBS isn't a better idea in this specific case.  With a MySQL *dump* file stored in EBS, there would be virtually no effective deduplication, because EBS snapshot deltas are block-level deltas (not file deltas).  A one byte offset anywhere in the one monolithic backup file would cause a shift that would throw off every subsequent block, causing them all to be different.  Effective delta storage of MySQL dumpfiles requires a tool that understands file deltas, like zpaq.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot and that's some good info about dump files on EBS. I wasn't trying to suggest that a switch to EBS would be a solution. I was simply trying to point out that S3 doesn't have that feature. I agree with you that EBS is not a better idea in this specific case. I would suggest continuing to use S3 in this specific case.

Comment: *"I wasn't trying to suggest that a switch to EBS would be a solution"*  You're right -- you didn't -- and I apologize that my comment does imply that you did.  I was anticipating someone seeing the information about EBS and jumping to that conclusion.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that distinction.  In my mind, I have always thought of versioning as a delta.  Too bad s3 doesn't do that.  I see no reason why they couldn't.